# Wrong language codes generated by Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.ManifestLanguages

Tags: localization, uwp

I am localizing my UWP app in several languages using the [Multilingual App Toolkit](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/develop/multilingual-app-toolkit) 
here are some screen shots of how the MultilingualResourcesFolder and the Strings folder looks like in the project

Multilingual Resources

[image]

Strings

[image]

All the files are filled with the correct values.

In the application I retrieve the list of available languages with
`Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.ManifestLanguages` and iterate through them. The iteration yields these results

- pt-PT
- ro-RO
- ru
- sk
- sl

This is very strange because the languages are declared in exaclty the same way but for some languages the language code includes the locale and for some it doesn't , for no reason I can undestand.

In the way I declare them the iteration should yield

- pt-PT
- ro-RO
- ru-RU
- sk-SK
- sl-SL

I have tried manually declaring the languages in the appxmanifest by replacing x-generate like this

```
<Resources>
    <Resource Language="ru-ru"/>
    <Resource Language="sk-sk"/>
    <Resource Language="pt-pt"/>
    <Resource Language="sk-sk"/>
    <Resource Language="sl-sl"/>
</Resources
```

but the results are the same.

I need to get the application to recognize the locale as well as the language for every language.
Can anybody help?

Comment: I can see this phenomenon. I'm currently investigating into it.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT if it helps you I am using VS 2015 Update 3

Comment: I'm seeing the behavior as well... I added several locales of Russian and when I look in the manifest, I only see RU. According to the documentation on the RCP-47 tag, if the locale is "irrelevant", it is left off. So, based on that, the assumption is that since the different locales in Russian don't actually differ, the locale isn't needed.

So I guess the key question... what are you trying to do WITH the locale that you need it? There is a C++ method "ResolveLocaleName" that might help, but I haven't tried hooking it up yet.

Comment: @DanteGagne I'm trying to display a list of all the available languages **with the locale name**, even if it is irrelevant(it is a requirement), for the user to choose. I am getting these names from the manifest using `ApplicationLanguages.Languages` and ,of course, if they are not correctly registered in the manifest they are not correctly displayed.

Comment: Ok, I'm following up with the Windows guys to see if I can get an answer. I'll respond as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got a solution for you. There's also a separate issue that you're dealing with, which is why x-generate in the manifest isn't doing the right thing (or is it?). I'm investigating that on the side.

So, this is the method you want:

```
public static string GetLocaleFromLanguage(string identifier)
{
    int result;

    StringBuilder localeName = new StringBuilder(500);
    result = LocaleFunctions.ResolveLocaleName(identifier, localeName, 500);

    StringBuilder localeDisplay = new StringBuilder(500);
    result = LocaleFunctions.GetLocaleInfoEx(localeName.ToString(), LCTYPE.LOCALE_SENGLISHDISPLAYNAME, localeDisplay, 500);
    return localeDisplay.ToString();
}
```

And of course, you're going to need the externs:

```
class LocaleFunctions
{
    // pInvoke declarations

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int GetLocaleInfoEx(String lpLocaleName, LCTYPE LCType, StringBuilder lpLCData, int cchData);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int ResolveLocaleName(string lpNameToResolve, StringBuilder lpLocaleName, int cchLocaleName);
}
```

Unfortunately, you're also going to need the declaration for LCTYPE. The code for that can be found at this link: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/LCTYPE.html
(It's a massive chunk of code and I don't want to just copy that here.

In my code, I manually added the following language resources to my manifest (again, I'm not sure why x-generate isn't adding the Russian locales here, but this works around it):

```
<Resources>
    <Resource Language="EN-US" />
    <Resource Language="ES-ES" />
    <Resource Language="ES-MX" />
    <Resource Language="PT-PT" />
    <Resource Language="RO-RO" />
    <Resource Language="RU-RU" />
    <Resource Language="RU-UA" />
</Resources>
```

And this is the method I'm using to call in:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string output = "";
    foreach (string thisManifestLanguage in Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.ManifestLanguages)
    {
        output += thisManifestLanguage + ": ";
        string ResolvedName = LocalizationTesting.LocaleTest.GetLocaleFromLanguage(thisManifestLanguage);
        output += ResolvedName + "\n";
    }

    this.outputText.Text = output;
}
```

When I called this, the output I got was:

```
en-US: English (United States)
es-ES: Spanish (Spain, International Sort)
es-MX: Spanish (Mexico)
pt-PT: Portuguese (Portugal)
ro-RO: Romanian (Romania)
ru: Russian (Russia)
ru-UA: Russian (Ukraine)
```

I should point out that in GetLocaleFromLanguage, localeName for "ru" gets "ru-RU", so if that's what you're looking for, that's available too.

Let me know if this doesn't meet with your needs. I'll see if I can get a reason about why in my case, I had to explicitly add ru-UA to my manifest.

Comment: The more I think about this though... these APIs give invariant versions of the languages. So, for instance, you're going to get "Russian" instead of "Русский". While they will give the values that can be used, they're really intended to be used in the underlying methods. That's why, as you can see, Spanish gives the unusual "Spain, International Sort" as the locale.A better solution might be to just add a "Locale Display Name" resource to each RESX table and display that value instead. That would also get around the manifest issue.

Comment: At the moment I have a hardcoded list with the language and locale names, and when the user chooses an option I handle the selection. However, it is more of a workaround rather than a solution.  From my understanding and from your earlier comment on the question, the behavior of leaving out the locale from the manifest when it is irrelevant is by design and according to documentation. So your answer is as close to a solution that utilizes the languages from the manifest as we are going to get. I'll try it out and accept this as the answer.

Comment: Corcus, is Windows not handling the UI for you automatically? I'm not questioning your design, but Windows is supposed to take care of these interactions automatically. If the user's UI is in language X, then Windows automatically puts the app into that UI. What, may I ask, is preventing you from using that system?

Comment: There is no problem with windows handling the UI automatically. When I set my language from Settings > Time & Language > Region and Language to ,say, Spanish then the app launches automatically in Spanish. No problem with that.

However, there is a requirement that the user be able to switch the application language from within the app and not (only) via the system wide settings. I did not make this requirement so I don't know exactly why it is so. I suspect it is for reasons of experience compatibility with other platforms this product already exists in.

Comment: Ok, well, hopefully the solution above works for you. I do rather think putting the language into the resource dictionary and pulling that might satisfy your needs better, but so long as you can meet the requirements of your app :).

Answer (score 0):

I'll let Dante follow up, but I'm curious why this list is interesting?  Eg: What's the user scenario?

A UWP lists the languages it can provide data for, and the Region & Language Settings collects a list of languages that the user understands.  So then Windows figures out which language best matches the user and app language and the resource loader uses that.  So I'm curious what scenario is missing?

Comment: When the app is first opened what you describe happens and the app is displayed in a language the user understands and the app provides. There is a requirement however that the user be able to change the language the application is displayed in from within the app. When the app restarts it should then be displayed in the new language. This is done by giving the user a choice from a list of languages and then using `ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride` . This list should be pulled from `ApplicationLanguages.Languages` which lists the languages the app provides.

Comment: The `ApplicationLanguages.Languages` list also facilitates displaying the languages in a localized manner ( Русский instead of Russian) etc. It is also a requirement in our application that the Language is displayed along with its locale eg. Spanish (Mexico). This is where the problem was. The list of languages pulled from the manifest did not contain the locale for languages where the locale was irrelevant.